# OnTearDown not being called in NUnit test

Tags: c#, nunit

I am to unit testing with NUnit and FakeItEsay. I have an issue as I have initialised some objects in the OnTearDown of the test expecting these will be readily available for all the tests that I write.

I am getting error in the tests as the objects are not initialised in any tests.

Am I missing something?

```
using FakeItEasy;
using NUnit.Framework;    
[TestFixture]
public classs A
{
   obj a;
}
[TearDown]
public void OnTearDown()
{
     a = new object();
}

[test]
public void testA()
{
   var x = a;
  // a, x are null here, why??
}
```

Comment: OnTearDown is run after all tests, so of course they are null before it runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TearDown is used to clean up *after a test method is finished*. In your example it would be called after testA finished so the attribute a is obviously not initialized.

Use the [SetUp Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-Attribute) to initialize your test environment. You should also consider using the [OneTimeSetUp Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute) to have an intialization method called once per *test fixture* instead of once per *test method*. If you really need to initialize the referenced object once per test method it may be better to explicitly call the initialization in the test methods themselves as that would reduce dependencies between methods.